# Can i call other application in eBook(epub)?

Tags: epub, epub3, epublib

I want to make ebook that can call other application.
For example, if reader of ebook clicks button or link, application like game will be executed. I thought it can be done by using Javascript but i couldn't find any information about it. If it is possible, please give me some hints.

p.s. My target platform is android tablet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. Imagine the horrifying possibilities for malware-infested e-books.

Your ability to talk to the outside world from inside e-books is limited to invoking links that will open up in a browser when an anchor tag is tapped.

If you want the kind of functionality you mention, you would need to write your own custom e-book reader which supports that.